# Is there a way of playing a video with a alpha channel on android?

Tags: android, video, camera, alpha, alpha-transparency

I have a set of video animations with an alpha channel. I would like the user of the android app to record a video and play the animation that overlay the camera view at the same time. I have searched the Internet but didn't find any solution to achieve this. Have you any ideas of how that can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

For Preview: 
You could try using opencv to read the video frame by frame and then overlay it with the camera frame and display it on a textureview.
[EDIT]: This doesn't work since opencv on android doesn't have the ability to extract frames from a video, as there is no native ffmpeg support.

For Recording:
You cannot record video this way and your best bet is to use ffmpeg to overlay the animation video on the recorded video.

Opencv4android: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html

Read Video frame by frame: (http://answers.opencv.org/question/5768/how-can-i-get-one-single-frame-from-a-video-file/)

Blending frames on opencv: (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html)

FFFMPEG on Android: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/931